# What kind of set does intersection/union return?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Im curious what kind of output intersection and union return.

For instance. Let M = {a,b,c} and N = {c,d,e} and O = {b,c,d}

Does $M ∩ N$ yield $c, \{c\}, or \{\{c\}\} $?

If it yields either of the first too, then $c ∈ M ∩ N$ should be true
and $M ∩ N ⊆ O$ should be true if the operation returns $\{c\}$

Comment: On the contrary, the only one that makes $c\in M\cap N$ true is the correct one: $M\cap N=\{c\}$. This is immediate from the definition of the intersection: it is the **set** of things belonging to both $M$ and $N$.

Comment: Thank you! If you post that as an answer, I'll tick the check :)

Comment: You’re welcome! I’ve done so, adding just a little more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the contrary, the only one that makes $c\in M\cap N$ true is the correct one: $M\cap N=\{c\}$. This is immediate from the definition of the intersection: it is the **set** of things belonging to both $M$ and $N$. Here $c$ is the only thing belonging to both $M$ and $N$, so the set of such things is the set containing $c$ and nothing else, i.e., the set $\{c\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of two sets is the set of things in both of those sets. Here $M$ contains $a,b$ and $c$, and $N$ contains $c,d$ and $e$, so the only thing both of these sets have in common is $c$, thus $M\cap N$ is the set containing $c$ which we write as $\{c\}$. If the intersection was $\{\{c\}\}$ this would imply that $\{c\}$ was an element of $M$ and $N$ which isn't true. It is a subset of both sets, but not an element.

There's nothing that says that the intersection can't contain sets though. For example if we had $A=\{\{0\},c,\text{dog}\}$ and $B=\{d,\text{cat},\{0\}\}$ then $\{0\}$ is the only element in both sets, so the intersection is the set containing $\{0\}$, thus $A\cap B=\{\{0\}\}$